# looking for a text editor which automates git commits upon closing the file

Tags: git, version-control

I have also posted this question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/8w9baz/looking_for_a_text_editor_which_automates_git/)

I'm not a version control or Git expert and it is very cumbersome for me to do all the steps manually. I want to have a text editor which upon closing the file if any changes were applied, runs these commands:

- checks if the file has been edited
- `git add <filename>`
- opens a popup or tab to edit the commit message
- `git commit -m "the commit message entered in the popup"`

I would appreciate it if you could help me know if there is such an editor to have this feature built-in or via a plugin/addon. Or if it is possible to write such a plugin.

**P.S.1.** It doesn't really have to be git, mercurial or other versions control systems are also fine.

**P.S.2.** I think this should be doable in Vim script and/or emacs lisp, If I knew those languages.

**P.S.3.** [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/how-to-make-an-autocommand-run-for-closing-a-window?newreg=a2c1176b089947d184438b1bc4d9b03f) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/653567/execute-a-command-when-vim-exits) different ideas have been discussed. It is apparently possible to git commit upon closing, but I want to write the message manually.

Comment: [vim-fugitive](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/)

Comment: If Michal's answer helps you solve the problem, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer? And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 5):

It should definitely be doable in any reasonably programmable editor.

Here, for example, is a definitely very buggy and incomplete first stab at a hook for Emacs + magit:

```
(defun my/auto-commit-on-kill ()
  (when buffer-file-name
    (let* ((current (magit-file-relative-name))
           (choices (nconc (magit-modified-files) (magit-untracked-files)))
           (to-stage (car (member current choices))))
      (when to-stage
        (magit-stage-file to-stage)
        (magit-commit)))))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'my/auto-commit-on-kill)
```

But actually if you were to go the Emacs/[magit](http://magit.vc) route I would strongly urge you to 
just use magit "manually". It's really not that complicated and yet it would teach you way more about git than relying on a even more simplified interface.

Comment: I haven't used emacs for a long long time now. would you be so kind to explain where this code should go?

Comment: If you really wanted to test it, your Emacs initialization file - probably ~/.emacs.d/init.el - is the place for setting this up. You would also need to install magit. But I bet the current version of my example is not good enough for real use. I'm something of an Emacs user, but definitely not an elisp expert.